# How to schedule a database update to run as soon as the device is connected to internet even if the app has been terminated

Tags: react-native

I want the user to be able to save changes even when they're offline and the app should update the database on the server with all the changes once the device is connected.

My first thoughts were to save all the requests as a stringfied array of objects in async storage and schedule a background task to run every 15 minutes and check if the device is connected and if the array of requests in async storage has a length of greater than zero then the requests get executed.

But the problem is when using a package like [react-native-background-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-fetch) that background task only runs when the app is still in memory and not terminated.

any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: **_even if the app has been terminated_** it was hard to do, something like `keep coding when you're sleep` :)

Comment: apps like whatsapp for example do it without a problem.. if you sent someone a text without an internet connection and terminated the app the text will be sent once the device is connected @flix

Comment: i don't think so, i've tried it using my Xiaomi device, and FYI i've activated `long back press: kill recent apps` something like `force stop` apps, while i'm not opening the whatsapp, even someone texting me whatsapp wouldn't show any notif/badges unless i'm open whatsapp apps manually